# Why isn't this HTML table working properly in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

Consider this simple HTML table:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed; width: 280px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px; width: 50px; border: 0; word-wrap: break-word;">a</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; width: 100px; border: 0; word-wrap: break-word;">b</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; width: 100px; border: 0; word-wrap: break-word;">c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This renders properly in every major browser, except in Chrome, in which the column widths bizarrely come out as 46px, 102px and 102px respectively.

If I take the CSS width declaration out of the table element, then it renders correctly in Chrome. But I need this in there, otherwise word-wrapping won't work correctly.

Any idea why this isn't working? I've tried different doctypes and this hasn't changed anything, so I'm assuming it's not an HTML5 table problem.

**EDIT:** It turns out that if you specify `table-layout: fixed` *and* a pixel width on the `table` element *and* pixel widths on each column, then Chrome will assume that your column widths *include* padding. This contravenes the W3C box model and is in violation of CSS2 required behaviour.

If you don't specify `table-layout: fixed` or you don't specify a pixel width on the `table` element, then Chrome will correctly assume your column widths that you specify *exclude* padding.  All other browsers assume that your column widths *exclude* padding.

In the example above, specifying the widths as 60px, 110px and 110px would fix the problem in Chrome but then break it in every other browser. The values of 46px, 102px and 102px come from Chrome evenly distributing the columns with a ratio of 40:90:90 instead of 50:100:100.

Comment: Just so it's said, inline styles are the devil.  They defeat the whole purpose of CSS.

Comment: @cHao Inline styles or declaring a CSS class does not make any difference for a simple example like this.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this problem myself today using `table-layout: fixed` and `box-sizing: border-box` to force Chrome to stop taking padding into account. Otherwise you never know what sizing model Chrome will pick, even for two very similar tables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my math says Chrome's doing what it should:

102 + 102 + 46 = 250px -> **Widths**

2(5) + 2(5) +2(5) = 10 + 10 + 10 = 30px -> **Padding**

Widths + Padding = 250 + 30 = **280px**, or the width you specified for the table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. They add up to 280px, yes, but I specified the `td` widths as 50px, 100px and 100px, so where do 46px, 102px and 102px come from?

Comment: Maybe the browser's just disappointed.  I mean, it's a program running on a computer, a device made for calculation, and you're not giving it any math to do.  So it's being passive-aggressive.  Try taking off the last width so it feels useful.  :)

Comment: @cHao: Haha. When I take the 100px width out of the 3rd `td`, Chrome does something even more strange. It assumes the first two widths _include_ padding, so gives them widths of 40px and 90px! When you miss out the last width in other browsers, they don't do this, and correctly calculate the final width as 100px. Bizarre.

Comment: I believe it is a result of the width constraint you placed on the **table** itself. It forces the cells themselves to fit within 280px, _total_, so when you specify the 10px of padding (5px on each side), the content of each cell is forced to squeeze in to fill what's left.

Comment: But 50+100+100=46+102+102, so it should work without adjusting. I've just found out that if I use 60px, 110px and 110px, with 280px on the table, it works properly in Chrome, but is then too big in all other browsers (as they add the padding). So it seems that if you set the total table width, Chrome stops using the W3C box model, and assumed widths include padding. But without a table width, Chrome correctly uses the W3C box model and adds padding to widths. This seems like a major problem to me...

Comment: @melkamo: If i take out `table-layout: fixed`, it seems to do the right thing in Chrome.

Comment: Ah yes, taking out `table-layout: fixed` seems to make it work across all browsers. That seems to break the box model in Chrome for some reason. Thanks both for your help, appreciated. :)

Comment: @cHao: maybe you should start a new reply, so that @melkamo can give you credit for answering the original question. Up to the both of you, though.

Comment: Oh dear: when I remove `table-layout: fixed`, the word-wrapping no longer works, even with the table width set to 280px. The table just grows wider to fit long words in.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the W3C spec says that's how it's supposed to work [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout). Hmm. Not very useful, am I?

Answer (score 1):

my method to fix this, executed for chrome browser only. We only use fixed tables in our web app and it seems working good, it's good to know that sometimes Chrome dimensions the col width perfectly, but sometimes not depending on where the table is located (and most of it inside what it's located).

```
                var correctedWidth;
                var extraSize;
                //chrome is taking the padding and border to calculate the column width , not other browsers
                $('table.default.fixed > thead > tr > th').each(function()
                {

                    if ($(this).attr('width')!='undefined' && $(this).attr('width')!=null)
                    {
                        if ($(this).attr('sizeUpdated')=="undefined" || $(this).attr('sizeUpdated')==null) {

                            extraSize = parseInt($(this).css('padding-left'))+parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'))+2; //2 for the borders (2*1px)

                            if ( parseInt($(this).attr('width'))!= $(this).width() )
                            {
                                correctedWidth=$(this).width()+2*(extraSize);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                correctedWidth=$(this).width()+extraSize;
                            }
                            $(this).attr('width',correctedWidth+'px');
                            $(this).attr('sizeUpdated','Y');

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing a parent element (fieldset) that had the following property:

```
display: inline-flex;
```

Answer (score -3):

It's better [not to use styles inline](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) within the HTML text.

Comment: What… is the problem exactly?

Comment: i think comments are in answer